# Prove that matrix expression is equal to $0$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose that $A$ and $X$ are square matrices and that I have the expression
$$A^\top X + XA=0$$
and I know that $A\neq 0$ and $X^\top = X$. Does this mean that $X=0$? Or can the equality hold even when $X\neq 0$? If $X$ and $A$ were scalars the solution would be obvious but since they are matrices I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: If $X^T = X$ this implies your problem is equivalent to solve the system $\left(A^T + A \right) X = 0$, If $A^T + A$ has full rank then yes, $X = 0$ otherwise in general $X = 0$ is a possible matrix that satisfies the equation. Also the matrix $B = A^T + A$ has the property $B^T = B$, so the problem, you want to find the solutions of the system $B X = 0$

Comment: "Does this mean that $X=0$?" Obviously not. Note that if $A$ is antisymmetric then $X=I$ solves this hence $X$ can even have full rank. In general, $A^TX+XA=0$ with $X^T=X$ means exactly that $A^TX+(A^TX)^T=0$ (and $X^T=X$), that is, that $A^TX$ is antisymmetric (and $X$ symmetric).

Comment: @user8469759 No, the problem is not equivalent to $(A^T+A)X=0$.

Comment: @Did, you're right. Sorry (I can't factor in that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counter example**

If $A^\top=-A$ and $X=I$ then $A^\top X + XA=0$

Comment: We have had the same idea.

Comment: @mfl Yes and we replied simultaneously :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $X=I$ and $A$ such that $A^T=-A.$ Then

$$A^TX+XA=-AI+IA=-A+A=0.$$